# Open audio with callback using ALSA

Tags: python, linux, audio, python-multithreading, alsa

Is it possible in Python, using ALSA, to access the audio hardware for playback, with a callback function:

```
def audiocallback():
    # create some audio and return a buffer of 1024 samples (~23 ms @ 44.1khz)
    # that is going to be played on the device
    return buffer

openaudio(deviceid=1, type=OUTPUT, freq=44100, buffersize=1024, callback = audiocallback)
```

**Would this be possible with `python-alsaaudio` ?** **Or another module related with ALSA, like SDL?** **Or by using a specific thread with `threading`?**

---

*Note:  is there an official mailing-list, repo, forum, etc. for `python-alsaaudio` ? I didn't find any active development.*

*Note 2: I don't want to use `PyAudio`, because when using it, I had various problems on Raspberry Pi: as it involves another layer, PortAudio, this probably increases the weight of this solution. I successfully used PyAudio on PC x86 projects, but on Pi, it seems too heavy for various reasons that would be too long to discuss here.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've succeeded in getting it to work with python-alsaaudio. There is no from-the-box method for this purpose, but it's relatively easy to implement.

```
import alsaaudio
import random
import struct

BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

def noise_callback():
    return [random.randint(-20000, 20000) for i in range(BUFFER_SIZE)]

def openaudio(card_name, freq, buffer_size, callback):    
    device = alsaaudio.PCM(card=card_name)

    device.setchannels(1)
    device.setrate(freq)
    device.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)

    device.setperiodsize(buffer_size)

    while True:
        samples = callback()
        data = struct.pack("h" * len(samples), *samples)
        device.write(data)

openaudio(card_name="default", freq=44100, buffer_size=BUFFER_SIZE, callback=noise_callback)
```

This example is continuously writing white noise to alsa default audio device until halted.

If you want to do something in parallel, you need to launch `openaudio` in separate thread. As I understand it is the only way, because documentation says `PCM_ASYNC` mode haven't been implemented yet.

Looks like the last commit to python-alsaaudio repository was in August of 2011. So hardly there can be any activities like forums or mail-lists. But its source code looks simple enough to quickly dig in. It's a plain wrapper.

The only information I've used is [documentation](http://pyalsaaudio.sourceforge.net/libalsaaudio.html) and `playwav.py` example from the python-alsaaudio package.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get it right.
But did you try "aplay"?

```
aplay /path/to/file/file.wav
```

But I think you can only play wav with that.
Sorry if that is not what you are looking for. ALSA is not that well documented especially for PI.

Comment: No, I don't want to play a .wav this way. I want to be able to open a device a send some data to the soundcard each 1024 samples, with a buffer, as usual in many audio applications.